# How to resolve issue from laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I am receiving this error when I try to get the value from database to edit bus type form text box.

```
Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: E:\fyp\resources\views\buses\editbustype.blade.php)
```

Here is the code for edit section of controller:

```
public function edit(addbustype $id)
{
    $bustype = addbustype::find($id);

    return view('buses.editbustype', compact('bustype','id'));
}
```

When I changed `$id` to any number (1) it gives me the perfect result for that id, but only for a single one. The code for edit bus type section is here:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="name">Company Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Company Name" value="{{$bustype->name}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Are You Try To Use Type Hinting To Crap The Result Or You Are Trying To Crap It With addbustype::find() methid?

Comment: I'm trying to find it with addbustype::find($id) , i get the error on this, when i changed ($id) to any number (1) it fetches the correct result of that id with out giving any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note That You Are Using [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding)

Than You Are Trying To Get The addbustype With $id Watch is $id Now Become An Instance Of addbustype Model So It Well Give You An Error Because 
   $bustype Well Now Become A Collection Of addbustype Model

So You Have To Decide Eather Use Route Model Binding Or Simply Find Function

In Your Web.php Route

The Parameter Name Must Matches With Parameter Both On Route And Edit Function

`Route::get('addbustype/{addbustype}','yourCountroller@edit')`

```
public function edit(addbustype $addbustype)
{

    return view('buses.editbustype', compact('bustype'));
}
```

Or Simply Use Find Method

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $bustype = addbustype::find($id);

   return view('buses.editbustype', compact('bustype','id'));
}
```

You Can Revel To Route Model Binding For [More](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: it is now working perfectly fine when i changed the route to Route::get('addbustype/{id}','AddbustypeController@edit');
but can you tell me the reason why this route " Route::resource('buses/addbustype', 'AddbustypeController'); " doen't give me the result, as it contains all the controller functions inside it

Comment: Did This Solved Your Issue?

Comment: You Could Use `λ php artisan route:list` To See Your All Endpoints This Well Work But When You Passing You Parameter Pass It Like This $id With Out Addbustype $id